# Closed-form expression of the following double integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How can I find closed-form expression of the following double integral
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\int_{0}^{\infty}{{\rm d}r\,{\rm d}\phi \over
u_{1}^{2} + u_{2}^{2}\,r + 2\,u_{1}u_{2}\,\sqrt{r\,}\,\cos\left(\phi\right)}\
{\large ?}
$$ Please help me as soon as you can.

Comment: Are you sure it is convergent? The integral with respect to $r$ diverges at infinity.

Comment: Are you missing a factor of like $1/r$ or $1/r^2$?

Comment: Hence the answer is: there is a closed-form expression, which is $+\infty$.